# Regex in Python to cut info from string

Tags: python, regex, sed

I try to get info from string like that :

> **008**_**X41**,**008**_20150831_2N,**008**_**X41**-**22:43**-008_20150831_2N

I need to cut bold sections. I try that:

```
re.search("(X[\d]*).*([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9])-([09]{3})_",trip[2])
```

But it can't cut from all lines i need (i call every time with new line in `trip[2]`).

When I use `sed` I write:

```
s/\(X[0-9]*\).*[^0-9]\([0-9]{3}\)[^0-9].*\([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\).*/ \1 \2 \3/g
```

How to do it in python?

Comment: What is characteristic to the bold sections, i.e. what are the rules for the regex to follow?

Comment: What is the final result that you expect? Also, in Python, you'd just need to remove backslashes in front of round brackets to convert literal `(` and `)` to grouping symbols. You can try your sed regex as is, just with that small change.

Comment: i expect 3  vars witch a=X99 b=33:33 c=009

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `re.sub`

```
re.sub(r'(X[0-9]*).*[^0-9]([0-9]{3})[^0-9].*([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]).*', r' \1 \2 \3', strin)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this  sed command also

```
sed 's/\([^,]\+,[^_]\+\)[^,]\+,\([^:]\+:[0-9]\{2\}\).*/\1 \2/' FileName
```

**OutPut:**

```
008_X41,008 008_X41-22:43
```